# A mixing problem with concentrations

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

These mixing problems trip me up sometimes and I was just wondering if my setup was correct. It asks: A tank with a capacity of 500 gallons originally contains 200 gallons of water with 100 lb. of salt in solution. Water containing 1 lb. of salt per gallon is entering at the rate of 3 gallons per minute, and the mixture is allowed to flow out of the tank at a rate of 2 gallons per minute. Find the concentration $C(t)$ of salt in the tank at any time t until it overflows. So the set up for the Cauchy problem I had was this:

\begin{align*}
C(0)&=\frac{1}{2}\\
\frac{dC}{dt}&=\frac{\text{rate of change of salt}}{\text{rate of change of fluid in tank}}\\
&=\frac{ \frac{1lb}{gal} \cdot \frac{3gal}{min}- \frac{2gal}{min}\cdot \frac{Clb}{gal}}{\frac{3gal}{min}-\frac{2gal}{min}}\\
&=\frac{\frac{3lb}{min}-\frac{2Clb}{min}}{\frac{1gal}{min}}\\
&= \frac{3lb}{gal}-\frac{2Clb}{gal}\\
&=3-2C
\end{align*}

and from there the solution is just algebra.

Comment: The intuition may be better if we find a DE for the *amount* $S(t)$ of salt in the tank at time $t$.